# Creating Markup Dynamically Jquery

Tags: jquery

I am attempting to create a bunch of list items dynamically, the structure I am looking for is

```
<li>
    <a href="Pending.aspx">
        <img src="images/gf.png" alt="" class="ui-li-icon">My Stuff
        <span class="ui-li-count">4</span> 
    </a>
</li>
```

I am attempting to create this structure with this code but it seems to be breaking when I add the "img" portion to it. If I take the img portion out it at least works but no quite what I am looking for. Any ideas on how to fix this?

```
 $('ul').append(
        $('<li>').append(
        $('<a>').attr('href', 'some link').attr('data-container', 'listview').append(
        //THIS BREAKS IT
        $('<img>').attr('src','some image').attr('alt','').append(
        $('<span>').attr('class', 'tab').append('1')
        ))));
```

I am trying to dynamically create the list items found here:
http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.1/docs/lists/lists-icons.html

Notice they have image tags that are NOT closed. That is how its valid to add the span tag I guess. Not sure how I can accomplish NOT closing the img tag in javascript?

Comment: How is it broken? Do you see an error?

Comment: With the img you probably want after not append.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, and it *should*: an `img` is a void element, it *cannot* have children, child-nodes or descendants of any kind.

To achieve what you seem to want (from reading your code), I'd suggest:

```
var list = $('<ul />').appendTo('body'),
    listElem = $('<li />').appendTo(list),
    link = $('<a />', {
        'href': 'pending.aspx',
        'class' : 'ui-li-icon'
    }).attr('data-container', 'listview').text('My Stuff').appendTo(listElem);
$('<img />', {
    'src': 'images/gf.png',
    'alt': 'alttext'
}).prependTo(link);
$('<span />', {
    'class': 'ui-li-count'
}).text('4').appendTo(link);​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/gBHQ3/1/).

Comment: Indeed, but if I tried to maintain the level of nesting you've got in your own answer I'd get lost three days later. I prefer to create single nodes, and then append/prepend to those created and identified elements, rather than creating a whole block of HTML at once. It's a personal thing, but I find my approach easier is all =)

Comment: I usually follow your approach. I was just having some fun ^_^.  That's why  your answer was 2 minutes faster than mine :-P

Comment: Ah, well; in *that* case..! =D

Comment: This code is is giveing me javascript error "Invalid character" on line }).text('4').appendTo(link);​

Comment: Yes, those are invisible characters that JS Fiddle seems to use in order to properly format and syntax-highlight the code. When copying from JS Fiddle, it's always best to remove ***all*** whitespace (outside of quote marks, quoted-strings) and then re-indent according to your preferences.

Answer (score 2):

Try to make it simpler.

It might work out much better for you :-)

```
$('ul').append(
   $('<li>', {
       html: $("<a>", {
           href: "some link", "data-container": "listview",
           html: $("<img>", {
               src: "some image", alt: "",
               html: $("<span>", {
                    class: "tab", html: "1"
               })
           })
       })
    })
);
```

Now you see what is wrong? an `img` cannot have a `span` as HTML! It actually cannot have **any** child node!

So what you can do is add the span *after* the image:

```
$('ul').append(
   $('<li>', {
       html: $("<a>", {
           href: "some link", "data-container": "listview",
           html: $("<img>", {
               src: "some image", alt: ""
           }).after($("<span>", {
                    class: "tab", html: "1"
               }))
       })
    })
);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/X3XDF/

Answer (score 0):

```
//assume arrayOfImageUrls and that these URLs have been sanitized on the front end

var frontText = '<li><a href="Pending.aspx"><img src="',
backText = '" alt="" class="ui-li-icon">My Stuff<span class="ui-li-count"></span></a></li>',
joinText = backText + frontText,

$_ulList = $('ul').append(frontText + arrayOfImageUrls.join(joinText) + backText);

$_ulList.find('li > .ui-li-count').each( function(i){ $(this).text(i); } );
```